# R access element in a vector that is in a list

Tags: r

how to access elements from a vector that resides in a list
not  clear why it works like in de code example
l[2] is a vector
l[2][1] is expected to refer to the 1st element of the vector

```
l <- list( 0, c(1,7,12))

l[2][1] # does not work, gives.....[1] 1  7  12

l[2][[1]][1] # does work as desired, gives [1] 1, but don no why
l[2][[1]][2] # gives [1] 7, as desired
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/5325862) should have you covered with the difference between `[` and `[[`

Answer (score 1):

Your can access it using `l[[2]][1]`

you can look at the output of `l` to see how items are organised. This can give you a clue as to how to call them

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1]  1  7 12
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you use the single bracket notation, R returns an element of the same class as the original object.

`l` is a `list`, so when you access an element of the list, e.g. `l[2]`, R returns the element you asked for but wrapped in a list.

```
> l[2]
[[1]]
[1]  1  7 12

> class(l[2])
[1] "list"
```

If you want to "peel away" this layer, you use the double bracket syntax. R will then return the actual object at that index.

```
> l[[2]]
[1]  1  7 12

> class(l[[2]])
[1] "numeric"
```

Now you can access the elements of the vector.

```
> l[[2]][1]
[1] 1

> l[[2]][2]
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use `pluck`, it is more easier

```
library(purrr)
pluck(l, 2, 1)
#[1] 1
```